# Angular 1 - Logic in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm

What is the best practice in this case.

Use the component for logic, in my HTML :

```
  <switch model="$ctrl.feature.roof"
              on-change="$ctrl.onChange()"> 
  </switch>
```

And in my component :

```
  onChnage(value) {
    this.feature.roof = value
  }
```

Or place the logic directly in the HTML with :

```
  <switch model="$ctrl.feature.roof"
              on-change="$ctrl.feature.roof = !$ctrl.feature.roof"> 
  </switch>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the place to ask for best practices. But I would go for the latter if and only if it does not have much importance to the rest of the scripts.

Comment: I second that this is not the best place to ask for best practices, but given that your code does exactly 1 small thing that's unlikely to be done elsewhere, it's probably OK to have inline, even though I try to extract logic to the $ctrl whenever possible. If you do go the $ctrl route, try to give a better name than "$ctrl.onChange()" though, something like `$ctrl.toggleRoofFeature()` is much more descriptive of what it does.